# How can I delete a node that is displayed in a view in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

Drupal 6.

I have created a node type which consists of just a body text field (the title is hidden using auto_nodetitles), and I am displaying all nodes of this type through a view.

I want the author of the node to be able to click a "delete" link somewhere next to the node item in the view to have it removed (as you would delete a node through /admin/content/node/overview normally).

What is the best approach to doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via Views, you can output node edit/delete links; however, you'll have to confirm the deletion as in the administrative pages.

I suggest you to write a custom module with the function to delete nodes, but without confirming. Write this simple module (you could use your existing custom module) following these steps:

1. Write an implementation of `hook_menu()`, which defines a menu item with wildcard to receive the node ID as argument (more on this [here](http://drupal.org/node/109153))
2. Add a function where you should pass the node ID and call [node_delete()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_delete/6)
3. In Views, add node:nid to the view's fields, but exclude this from display
4. Add a custom text view field (in options pick output this as link), and write URL you've chosen in 1
5. Don't forget to use "[nid]" as wildcard
6. Profit.